# Geohash in redis with php

Tags: php, redis, geohashing

I am using Redis with php and its library **phpredis**.

I have the following structure:

```
city:1 {
 lat->14.02,
 lon->10.00,
 hash->sp2f1h60w5j
}

city:2 {
 lat->14.03,
 lon->10.1,
 hash->sp2f1h60w5m
}
```

But I haven't found a way to search by hash. I would like to search for example the exact same hash or approximately the same hash.
Should I change my structure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could follow Josiah Carlson's advice [from this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/redis-db/Mw0lRzutnkE%5B1-25%5D), and convert the hash into a number, and use that as a score in a sorted set. Something like this:

```
city:1 {
 lat->14.02,
 lon->10.00,
 hash->sp2f1h60w5j
}

city:2 {
 lat->14.03,
 lon->10.1,
 hash->sp2f1h60w5m
}
```

To use the geohashes as numbers, you need to decode them from base 32 using a particular character map -- see [Geohash on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash). I'll use example numbers below.

```
cities { (1, 4711), (2, 4712) }
```

Now you can use [zrangebyscore](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) to find cities in an area:

```
zrangebyscore cities 4000 5000
```

Comment: You could also have a look at how it is done in the https://github.com/doat/geodis package.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use the key in redis to get the elements.

like:

city-sp2f1h60w5j = 1

city-sp2f1h60w5m = 2

then if you wish the closets:
get by "key":
city-sp2f1h60w*
if will return "array" of keys... or city id's. Can't remember the exact return data.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to find all items near a specific point? Since you're looking for exact or near match, I assume that's the case. Redis just released brand new Geo functionality yesterday (http://redis.io/commands#geo).

GeoRadius and GeoRadiusByMember are the ones you're looking for.